# How to add additional options on Symfony EntityType form widget?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a filter form in Symfony, which can filter for an Entity. For this purpose, I have a field with an `EntityFilterType` (`Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type\EntityFilterType`), which simply extends Symfony's builtin `EntityType`.

Now I want to add an "all" and a "none" option to this `EntityType`. If it was a `ChoiceType`, I would simply change the `choices` array, but the `EntityType` only accepts valid Entity-IDs as its value on submit and also only Entities in the array given to the 'choices' option.

My question is: How can I add additional options to an `EntityType` form field? Besides the ugly way to reimplement the Entity-stuff into a `ChoiceType` field? Any ideas on this? Am I missing a documented way?

Greets,
spackmat

Comment: You needs something more that `query_builder` option to filter entities?

Comment: The `query_builder` defines the queries, that limit the entities listed to chose in the widget. I need, on top of that, some more options/choices that are not entities, but other values that the controller (or in my case the filter logic) can use.

Comment: Well, `None` option can be the `'placeholder' => 'None'` form option, right ?

Comment: and `All` option (the undefined yet) should be allowed only when `'multiple' => true` form option, right ?

Comment: Apart from these two options you need other filters that select entities from this `choices`?

Comment: In my special case, there is a difference between the placeholder option (no filter at all) and the none-of-them option. And of course, the all option is only useful in `'multiple' => true` scenarios. My question is a bit abstract on purpose. :) At the moment, there are two filter items: One for "has any entity", "has no entity" and an empty placeholder and one for specific entities. This could be easily handled within one select-widget from the UX point of view.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking about `EntityType::class` form extension workaround but I'm not sure what do you needs exactly.

Comment: This would be a better way than implementing Entity-specific code into a ChoiceType::class. Thanks, a good idea. I hoped that there is a simpler way and people having the same problem.

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but you could use FormEvents or a Data transformer to glom on to the field during submission or rendering of the field. Does that jibe with what you're hoping for?

Comment: @CameronHurd this could work, too. But I have concerns, that the builtin validation of the EntityType won't accept invalid values and thus must be hacked, too. So I'll first try extending the EntityType::class. Or I'll simply use a ChoiceType and load the options manually from the repository.

Comment: I took a look into `EntityType::class` and its parent `DoctrineType::class` and implementing this would not be that easy. So I sticked with my additional `ChoiceType::class` filter for my case, hoping for an easy way to extend the choices of the `EntityType::class` in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some years have passed and the setting shines up again:

I have a ManyToMany related Entity that I want to filter for using the LexikFormFilterBundle. But I also want to allow to filter explicitly for Entities that have no such related Entity. In my case I want to allow to filter for ToDos that are assigned to some specific Users, but allow also to filter for ToDos that are not assigned at all. So the problems begin.

See also [that issue at LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/issues/293)

My solution for now is, indeed, switching to a `ChoiceType::class` and that looks like this:

```php
// We are in a buildForm function of a Filter-Form extending
// Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType and using The LexikFormFilterBundle

// prepare the choices with a "none"-choice on top
// feel free to add also a "all"-choice, if that is needed
$myChoices = [
    'None of those' => 'none',
];
foreach ($this->myWhateverRepository->getMyChoices() as $myChoice) {
    // where $myChoice is some related Entity
    $myChoices[$myChoice->getIdentifyingName()] = $myChoice->getId();
}
/*
anyhow, we now we have an array like this:
[
    'None of those' => 'none',
    'One related Entity' => 2,
    'Another related Entity' => 4,
]
*/

$builder    
    ->add('relatedWhatevers', ChoiceFilterType::class, [
        'choices' => $myChoices,
        'multiple' => true, // or false, but then the closure for apply_filter must be implemented in simpler way
        'label' => 'Filter for related whatevers',
        'required' => false,
        'apply_filter' => function (QueryInterface $filterQuery, string $field, array $values): ?ConditionInterface {
            if (empty($values['value'])) {
                // nothing to filter here
                return null;
            }

            // for multiple=true make sure, the $value is an ArrayCollection,
            // as the ChoiceFilterType gives us a plain array
            // that does not work in the LexikFormFilterBundle at least until 7.0.3
            // otherwise just take that one value for multiple=false
            $value = new ArrayCollection($values['value']);
            $whatevers = $value->filter(function(int|string $v) { return 'none' !== $v; });

            // join the related field and don't forget to do that as an
            // innerJoin, otherwise the isNull() doesn't find anything
            $queryAlias = 'myWhatevers';
            $filterQuery->getQueryBuilder()->innerJoin($field, $queryAlias);

            // for multiple=false that construct can be reduced to last two variants
            if ($value->contains('none')) {
                if ($whatevers->count() > 0) {
                    // we have 'none' and at least one other value to filter for
                    return $filterQuery->createCondition(
                        $filterQuery->getExpr()->orX(
                            $filterQuery->getExpr()->isNull($queryAlias),
                            $filterQuery->getExpr()->in($queryAlias . '.id', ':p_whatevers')
                        ),
                        ['p_whatevers' => $whatevers],
                    );
                }
                return $filterQuery->createCondition(
                    // we only have 'none', so the filter is less complex
                    $filterQuery->getExpr()->isNull($queryAlias),
                    [],
                );
            }
            return $filterQuery->createCondition(
                // no 'null' selected, so we just use that standard expression for related entities
                $filterQuery->getExpr()->in($queryAlias . '.id', ':p_whatevers'),
                ['p_whatevers' => $whatevers],
            );
        },
    ])
;
```

And that works: I can find ToDos assigned to some Users and/or are assigned to nobody. And when I don't fill the field, the filter does not do anything.